# Regex timeouts when to many -

Tags: c#, regex

This is way above my level of regex knowledge. I haven't worked that much with regex before but this is the first time i have encountered that a regex timeouts.

What I'm trying to do is to find the matching word + 3 words before and 3 after in Instagram posts. As you know some Instagram posts just is too weird.

This is the (truncated) Instagram post:

```
 ⏬⏬
WA ☎ :  --------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------

----------------------------------------------------------------------------
-------------
  
------------------------------------------------------------
#paytrenustyusufmansur
#bisnisberkah
#fintech
#MUI
#bisnissyariah
#PokokNyaPAYTRENinAJA
#PaytrenAcademy
```

and this is my regex:

```regex
\s*([a-zA-Z0-9åäöÅÄÖ_\-]+\W+){0,3}(\bPokokNyaPAYTRENinAJA(?![^.,!?\s]))(\W+[a-zA-Z0-9åäöÅÄÖ_\-]+){0,3}\s*
```

Here I'm trying to match the word `"PokokNyaPAYTRENinAJA"` and that works fine if i remove all the `"-"` characters, but somehow the regex can't handle all that `"-"` and it times out.

Comment: Just throwing this out there: Have you considered simply parsing your string instead of using a RegEx?

Comment: Could you please add explanation and code sample for "regex timeouts"?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer how do you mean i could parse the string to find the word in the text i'm looking for?

Comment: `[a-zA-Z0-9åäöÅÄÖ_\-]+` and `\W+` overlap in matching the `-` character, causing the backtracking. Atomic groups might help you out here.

Comment: @rudolf_franek you could try this https://regex101.com/r/7pjpaM/1 even tho that is js and not C# i get the same error in my c# code.

Comment: Sebastian is right. Just replace `\W+` with `[^\w-]`. And remove `\b` as it is redundant. See [this PCRE demo](https://regex101.com/r/h780fT/1), no CB is observed (and .NET regex is more efficient when it comes to catastrophical backtracking, BTW).

Comment: @DanielGustafsson Whatever you are trying to find follows some kind of logic. In your case probably something like *"A word is delimited by spaces, find word X and the three before and after that"*. If you simply split your string with by `' '` (or whatever rules apply) this should be a lot easier/faster.

Comment: thanks sebastian and wiktor! That worked great! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the two subsequent subpatterns that are placed in a quantified group. The `([a-zA-Z0-9åäöÅÄÖ_-]+\W+){0,3}` part is repeated from 0 to 3 times, and both `[a-zA-Z0-9åäöÅÄÖ_-]+` and `\W+` can match `-` (a non-word char). Since the regex engine tries all possible ways to match the text using backtracking, the number of steps becomes huge in cases like this.

The solution is to subtract `-` from `\W`.

You may use

```
\s*([a-zA-Z0-9åäöÅÄÖ_-]+[^\w-]+){0,3}(PokokNyaPAYTRENinAJA(?![^.,!?\s]))([^\w-]+[a-zA-Z0-9åäöÅÄÖ_-]+){0,3}\s*
```

Or, a .NET style:

```
\s*([a-zA-Z0-9åäöÅÄÖ_-]+[\W-[-]]+){0,3}(PokokNyaPAYTRENinAJA(?![^.,!?\s]))([\W-[-]]+[a-zA-Z0-9åäöÅÄÖ_-]+){0,3}\s*
```

The `[\W-[-]]` is a character class with [character class subtraction](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclasssubtract.html) where `\W` matches any non-word char but `-`.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cs*%28%5ba-zA-Z0-9%c3%a5%c3%a4%c3%b6%c3%85%c3%84%c3%96_-%5d%2b%5b%5cW-%5b-%5d%5d%2b%29%7b0%2c3%7d%28PokokNyaPAYTRENinAJA%28%3f!%5b%5e.%2c!%3f%5cs%5d%29%29%28%5b%5cW-%5b-%5d%5d%2b%5ba-zA-Z0-9%c3%a5%c3%a4%c3%b6%c3%85%c3%84%c3%96_-%5d%2b%29%7b0%2c3%7d%5cs*&i=%f0%9f%91%a4+%e2%8f%ac%e2%8f%ac%0d%0aWA+%e2%98%8e+%3a++--------------------------------------------------------------------%0d%0a---------------------%0d%0a%f0%9f%94%98%0d%0a----------------------------------------------------------------------------%0d%0a-------------%0d%0a%f0%9f%94%98++%0d%0a------------------------------------------------------------%0d%0a%23paytrenustyusufmansur%0d%0a%23bisnisberkah%0d%0a%23fintech%0d%0a%23MUI%0d%0a%23bisnissyariah%0d%0a%23PokokNyaPAYTRENinAJA%0d%0a%23PaytrenAcademy).